# Why doesn't tee use tee

Tags: linux, system-calls, gnu-coreutils

There is a gnu coreutils program 'tee' and a linux(/libc?) syscall 'tee'. The program tee does not call tee. Instead it 'read's and then 'fwrite's (multiple times of course).

Why doesn't tee use tee? I assume this is either for performance or portability, but I could not find an answer.

Followup question, why does it 'read' and 'fwrite', instead of either 'read'/'write' or 'fread'/'fwrite'?

Comment: The `tee(1)` command existed before the [`tee(2)` syscall](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tee.2.html). Why change it now?

Comment: I'm speculating, but for what `tee` is doing, input buffering would get in the way, but output buffering is still beneficial.

Comment: GNU tee is written to work under any Unix-like OS.  I think the tee syscall is Linux-only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tee(2)` only works between pipes. `tee(1)` needs to work between regular files, as in `tee file2 < file1 > file3`.

For more details, see [`man 2 tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tee.2.html).

Comment: Ah! I got confused with splice, which only requires 1 fd to be a pipe. Thanks